# Two coupled substitutions in single command line?

Tags: bash

This works great:

```
ls /path/{foo,bar}/
```

Now, what if I want to effectively do:

```
cp /path/foo/bunch/of/stuff/foo.txt /path/bar/bunch/of/stuff/bar.txt
```

Is there some short-hand I can do on a single command line?

I.e. kinda like `cp /path/{foo,bar}/file.txt` but where there are two substitutions that must be done simultaneously?

Effectively, I want multiple coupled brace expansions that do not yield all possible combinations.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution can include `/`:

```
cp /path/{foo/foo,bar/bar}.txt
```

is equivalent to

```
cp /path/foo/foo.txt /path/bar/bar.txt
```

An alternative approach would be to search-and-replace; this works as long as "foo" doesn't contain slashes:

```
set /path/foo/bunch/of/stuff/foo.txt; cp $1 ${1//foo/bar}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [history interaction](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction), but for the current line (`!#`):

```
$ echo /path/foo/bunch/of/stuff/foo.txt  !#:1:gs/foo/bar/
echo /path/foo/bunch/of/stuff/foo.txt  /path/bar/bunch/of/stuff/bar.txt
```

- `!#`, as already said, refers to the current line
- `:1` to the first word
- `:s/foo/bar` substitutes `bar` for `foo`
- `g` is a modifier which makes the substitution over the whole line

Comment: One interesting side-effect of this approach is that the expanded line is what ends up stored in the shell's history.

Comment: @StephenKitt oh, history interaction is never directly recorded in the history, is it? (As in, only the effects are seen in the history)

Comment: I think so, yes; at least a quick look through the `bash` manual didn't reveal any option to allow recording the pre-history-expansion version of a command.